# Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(, run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, python-3.10

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (150, 150, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

I'm trying to make food detection system using CNN

Comment: Please provide us the `TensorFlow version` detail to assess you better in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the basics of TensorFlow versioning, [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/basics) was introduced in TF2.0 onwards whereas you are using version <TF2.0 which uses `Graph Execution`. TF2.0 on the other hand uses `Eager Execution` . You can refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly).

To enable eager mode in tf 1.x, you need to run this code as follows :

```
# Tested on tf 1.15.1
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
tf.executing_eagerly() # True
```

The best option here is to run the code in Tensorflow 2.0.